# Using an object's id() as a hash value

Tags: python, hash

is it a bad idea to implement `__hash__` like so?

```
class XYZ:
    def __init__(self):
        self.val = None

    def __hash__(self):
        return id(self)
```

Am i setting up something potentially disastrous?

Comment: You mean, without implementing `__eq__()`? Most definitely a bad idea.

Comment: @JeffMercado the default `__eq__` is identity, so why would it _definitely_ be a bad idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `__hash__` method has to satisfy the following requirement in order to work:

Forall x, y such that `x == y`, then `hash(x) == hash(y)`.

In your case your class does not implement `__eq__` which means that `x == y` if and only if `id(x) == id(y)`, and thus your hash implementation satisfy the above property.

Note however that if you *do* implement `__eq__` then this implementation will likely fail.

Also: there is a difference between having a "valid" `__hash__` and having a *good* hash. For example the following is a valid `__hash__` definition for **any** class:

```
def __hash__(self):
    return 1
```

A good hash should try to distribute uniformly the objects as to avoid collisions as much as possible. Usually this requires a more complex definition.
I'd avoid trying to come up with formulas and instead rely on python built-in `hash` function.

For example if your class has fields `a`, `b` and `c` then I'd use something like this as `__hash__`:

```
def __hash__(self):
    return hash((self.a, self.b, self.c))
```

The definition of `hash` for tuples should be good enough for the average case.

Finally: you should not define `__hash__` in classes that are mutable (in the fields used for equality). That's because modifying the instances will change their hash and this will break things.

Comment: While you're correct in saying that this `__hash__` satisfies the properties required of it (as long as `__eq__` isn't defined), defining this `__hash__` offers no benefit over just inheriting `object.__hash__`.

Answer (score 3):

It's either pointless or wrong, depending on the rest of the class.

If your objects use the default identity-based `==`, then defining this `__hash__` is pointless. The default `__hash__` is also identity-based, but faster, and tweaked to avoid always having the low bits set to 0. Using the default `__hash__` would be simpler and more efficient.

If you objects don't use the default identity-based `==`, then your `__hash__` is wrong, because it's going to be inconsistent with `==`. If your objects are immutable, you should implement `__hash__` in a way that would be consistent with `==`; if your objects are mutable, you should not implement `__hash__` at all (and set `__hash__ = None` if you need to support Python 2).

Answer (score 1):

This is the default implementation of `__hash__`. Be aware, that implementing `__eq__` causes the default `__hash__` implementation to disappear. Should you reimplement `__hash__` then any objects that compare equal **must** have an equal hash.

It is okay for non-equal objects to have the same hash value though. Therefore, having a hash implementation that returns a constant value is always safe. However, it is very inefficient.

A good default that works for a lot of use cases is to return a hash of the tuple of the attributes that are used in the `__eq__` method. eg.

```
class XYZ:
    def __init__(self, val0, val1):
        self.val0 = val0
        self.val1 = val1

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.val0 == other.val1 and self.val1 == other.val1

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash((self.val0, self.val1))
```